# How should we handle blatantly incorrect edit summaries?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edit-summary

Sometimes people edit a post and leave an edit summary that is completely unrelated to their edit:

- [One example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11819435)
- [Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11380247)

It's hard to tell whether these summaries are due to carelessness or other motives and it doesn't seem worth flagging the post for a mod except in extreme cases.

Is there anything that can/should be done besides rejecting the edit? Is rejecting the edit even a good option if the edit itself is useful?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon's_razor

Comment: I wonder if there's something else going on here. Your second example shows the code being indented by another user prior to the OP's edit: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35587850/revisions Are edits that make the same change perhaps merged by SO in some way, leaving the edit message intact?

Comment: While I don't think it's important, both of your samples in fact have inconsistent comments about what actually was edited. I don't see any reason to reject them tgough.

Comment: @HansPassant assuming we do this, it still doesn't answer the question of how to deal with such stupidity (which was really the point of this discussion anyhow).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that inconsistency is what they were exemplifying...

Comment: "improved formatting"

Comment: Ban them.  Definitely lock their accounts in a bear trap and ban them.

Comment: I've seen my edit summaries end up in the edit summary of someone who edited a post after I did. Perhaps that's what's happening here?

Comment: It took me a while but I found an example: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34255729/revisions - I assumed what happened was that the subsequent editor did an "Accept and Edit" on my edit in order to put the bit about the code being homework back into the question.

Comment: @BSMP while that does happen with "Accept and Edit", viewing the edit history pretty clearly shows that's not the case here.

Comment: As someone who has done a whole lot of editing, my browser remembers all my prior edit summaries. I'll usually select one from that list. It's pretty easy to slip up and select the wrong one. The other thing is, it's easy to forget what you've changed (I often use undo), especially since editors do not have the comparison screen.

Comment: `[tag:feature-request]` Yeah, there should really be some functionality allowing us to edit edit summaries. One would also have to provide a summary of that edit summary edit. And turtles all the way down.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Often the summary can be ignored. I see no particular need to provide precise summaries in most cases.

My steps to review:

- *Glance* at the summary to avoid adding inappropriate content on the site.
- Evaluate the edit first. If you have no reservations to approve or reject the change  - ignore the summary altogether and accept/improve/reject.
- If there are concerns about the edit (like a code change or significant update) - read the summary. If the summary has a plausible explanation - thoroughly evaluate the change and vote appropriately, otherwise (like an unreadable/unrelated summary) - reject and move on.

The only case you'd really need to do something about the summary if it is unacceptable AND you find/feel that there is pattern for a particular user, flagging the user (i.e. flag "other" for any post by that user) would be appropriate for moderators to take action. You may consider adding a comment to the user if you think the user can respond positively (in that case postpone flagging). Make sure to vote to reject the change - it is yours (as a member of SO community) and not moderators' responsibility to take an action to remove questionable content.

Note: Sometimes multiple edits (especially code formatting and spelling) can effectively cancel each other and render the summary obsolete. This very well could be the case in linked edits.

Comment: @PeterMortensen, Thanks for adding "the". (I should just provide pile of "the" and the end of post for people to use :) )  I've tried to reword one sentence - please check if it is better.

Comment: I agree with this, but disagree with the 'summary not required' part. If anything, reviewers need to read the edit summary *more* than not at all, especially those edits which fix links and other critical parts of the post and are rejected simply because the editors don't read the edit summary.

Comment: It would seem the large swathe of edits with useless/irrelevant summaries have conditioned reviewers to stop looking at the summary.

Answer (score 5):

We are all human, and we all make mistakes, including users who edit posts. IMHO, you should ask yourself if the edit ultimately improves the post or not. If it does, despite the incomplete or incorrect edit summary, it should be approved. If the summary itself disqualifies the edit (e.g., includes profanity), you should reject it.

Answer (score 3):

To start with, moderators can modify edit summaries [as explained here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273359/165773):

> [image]

If you believe that edit summary is actively harmful to the site and *if you can explain* it in the flag message, you can flag the edited post for mod attention asking for their help.

That said, you need to take into account that edit summaries are really obscure and vast majority of site visitors won't notice them or even know about their existence. This means that moderator will likely decline the flag if it's only about simple mismatch of the summary and edit content because it is hard to imagine how this could be harmful.

As for rejecting the suggestion of an otherwise solid edit for the only reason of summary mismatch, this feels like overkill.

I can only imagine it being (mildly) troublesome if you notice particular editor making this mistake a lot. But even then, it's not necessary to start addressing it with flagging or rejecting their edits. System allows you to [notify the editor in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/36055/165773) of the post they edited, you can use comments to ask them pay more attention to the summary next time.